# cd in parent shell with python script

Tags: bash, python

I want my python program to `cd` into a directory via terminal as a parent process. Is there any way to do this?

I was hoping for something like this:

```
$ ./cd.py Desktop/scripts
$ pwd
/home/mfto/Desktop/scripts
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't be okay with just `$CDPATH`?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, and you'll find that `cd` is not actually a "*program*" in the normal sense - it's not a file on disk that can be executed, it is instead a "*built-in*" command. Built-in commands are interpreted by the shell itself (e.g: `bash`). For a list of `bash`'s built-in commands, see the ["*Shell Builtin Commands*" section of the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (or use the `help` built-in).

If `cd` was not built-in to the shell, then it would be impossible to change directory without forking a new process each time (which would be very messy).

This is because the current working directory (like the environment) is a property of a process. These things can be inherited from a parent to a child, but cannot be "*pushed*" back up from children to parents.

If you really want to have a python script change the current working directory and then present a shell, you will need to do something like this:

#### `cd.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

os.chdir('/tmp/')
os.system('bash')
```

#### Usage:

```
$ pwd
/home/attie/
$ echo $$
30665                  # the original shell's PID

$ ./cd.py

$ pwd
/tmp
$ echo $$
30464                  # the sub-shell's PID... it's parent is python

$ exit
exit

$ pwd
/home/attie/
$ echo $$
30665                  # the original shell's PID
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Changes to the working directory can only affect the current process (and any future children).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a workaround via bash's eval if you print the cd-Command you want to execute in your Python-Skript. But keep in mind, that eval is quite insecure (e.g. if your Python-Skript prints things like `rm -rf /*`).

```
cd.py() {
  eval "$( python ~/cd_.py $@ )"
}
```

```
# cd_.py:
import sys

target_dir = f"~/{sys.argv[1]}" # whatever you want to do with the arguments
print(f'cd "{target_dir}"') # Print 'cd path/to/file'
```